# Problems with boot (Ubuntu tty1-)

Tags: boot, login, gnome-shell, python3, source-packages

I used the command sudo apt autoremove python3 and now my ubuntu does not boot properly. It keeps going to Ubuntu tty1-. Would be grateful if someone could assist me.in fixing it.

Comment: You've provided no Ubuntu product & release details thus limiting what help we can provide.  Python3 is required for GUI & Ubuntu Desktop to function, so the impact on a Desktop system is more severe than if you're using a text based Server install; but the fix is to re-install the python3 package; which may require avoiding front-end tools like `apt`, ie. using `wget` & `dpkg` to install (until python3 is restored, tools that require it will not reliably function)

Comment: FYI:   You'll get most operation back the moment you have `python3-minimal` installed for your *unstated* product (I am assuming that you're using a *year.month* product of Ubuntu though)

Comment: Sorry it's Ubuntu 22.04.2

Comment: I just ran python3 -- version in ttyl and it says python 3.10.6

Answer (score 0):

First, login to the TTY-shell with your username and password.

Then, install python and other desktop packages for Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt install python3-all ubuntu-desktop
```